# XSLT not to return results

Tags: xslt

I am working inside of an application that I did not build.

the application requires a `True/False` from the XSLT File, Sort of, if the XSLT returns anything it is True, if it returns nothing it is false.  this is used by the application to decide whether or not to publish out the XML to a Web Service.

so I first started with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="{{if this is true I don't want anything returned}}">

   </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

{I figured that this would do the trick, but I was wrong it was still returning.
if I try when it is not there the application still publishes out the XML's that I don't want it to.}

so then I tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="{{if this is true I don't want anything returned}}">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes" />
   </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it terminated the transformation, sending an Error to the application and the error was caught by the application and kept the next XML from going through the Publishing Process.

what I need is to keep the XSLT File from Returning Results, on Command.

Maybe I don't fully understand how XSLT functions and I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What framework or process is executing the XSLT transforms? A shell script? A .BAT file? A program?

Comment: it is a Windows application. other than that I don't know much about the inner workings of the application. I think it is a web based application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />    

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="{{if this is true I don't want anything returned}}" />
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:text>Return something</xsl:text>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should return an absolutely nothing at all if the test evaluates as true.

Another variant would be to use match expression specificity:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />    

 <!-- empty template with a more specific match expression -->
 <xsl:template match="/*[{if this is true I don't want anything returned}]" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>Return something</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However in this approach you are limited to testing nodes from the input document in the match expression. Variables do not work in match expressions.

Comment: what do you mean by variables?  you mean like picking the node by attribute?  I tried the first example and it is still publishing the XML's that I don't want it to.

Comment: I re-read the documentation and need to do something totally different.  thank you for your help in understanding XSL a little bit better.

Comment: I have a Process where you can add several conditions (xpath or XSL Statements) and there is an existing one already there, so I thought I would just add an additional condition (the one I need). I assumed that it would only publish if both were true, but that is not the case it will publish if one of the many are true.  so I have to lump it together into one condition to make it work the way I need it to. thank you again

Answer (score 2):

The output of an XSLT stylesheet is always an XML document conforming to the XPath data model. That doesn't necessary mean it's well formed XML; for example it can be a document node with no children (an empty document). This is probably the closest you will get to outputting "nothing". The way you test for this "nothing" will depend on your calling application. In practice I would recommend outputting a "something" that's easy for your application to test for; for example a document containing the single empty element `<nothing/>`.

Comment: I understand that. thank you for taking the time to respond. I had been doing it right all along and was understanding the output properly, but I had assumed that my calling application would only publish if both of my conditions were true, but it was publishing if any of the conditions were true. so I had to combine both of the conditions into the one XSL.  little hard to explain, but I completely understand what was going on and solved my issue, completing my task.  again thank you for taking time to answer my question.